# Mean aunt is reincarnated as a fly with one green(?) eye and one brown eye

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I’m looking for a story I read. A boy's American parents are killed in an accident in India or Tibet.  He's sent back to live with his maiden aunt (who has one brown and one green (or blue) eye) in Kansas(?), where she makes him attend her church and tries to overcome his heathen Buddhist beliefs.  One day she disappears and the boy notices an angry fly, with one brown eye and one green eye, stuck on the flypaper...

The story is from the 1960s, or thereabouts.

Comment: When you say 'plus or minus', could you please specify what this means?  It's rather ambiguous at this point.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**I'm looking for a story I read.**

["The Cold Green Eye"](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?57682) by [Jack Williamson](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/ea.cgi?256).

**A boy's American parents are killed in an accident in India or Tibet. He's sent back to live with his maiden aunt (who has one brown and one green (or blue) eye) in Kansas(?),**

> "Kansas?" The boy looked hard at his teacher. "Where is Kansas?"
>
> "I do not know." The withered old monk shrugged vaguely. "The spring caravan will carry you down out of our mountains. A foreign machine called a railway train will take you to a city called Calcutta. The lawyers there will arrange for your journey to Kansas."
>
> "But I love our valley." Tommy glanced out at the bamboo plumes nodding above the old stone walls of the monastery garden and the snowy Himalayas towering beyond. He turned quickly back to catch the holy man's leathery hand. "Why must I be sent away?"
>
> "A matter of money and the law."
>
> **[. . .]**
>
> The hired man stopped the truck beside a huge wooden house that stood like a fort in the middle of the endless land, and Tommy's aunt came to greet him with a moist kiss. A plump, pink-skinned blonde, with a sweet, smooth, sweat-beaded face. He was used to darker women, and she seemed incredibly fair.
>
> "So you're Lizzie's boy?" She and her sister had come from Alabama, and soft Negro accents still echoed in her voice. "Gracious, honey, what's the matter?"
>
> Tommy had run to meet her eagerly, but he couldn't help shrinking back when he saw her eyes. The left was warm and brown and kind as old Chandra Sha's. But the right eye was different, a frosty, greenish blue; it seemed to look straight through him.

**where she makes him attend her church and tries to overcome his heathen Buddhist beliefs.**

> "What I can't forgive is all she did to you." Aunt Agatha snuffled and dabbled at her fat, pink nose. "Carrying you to all those outlandish foreign places. Letting you associate with all sorts of nasty natives. The lawyers said you've had no decent religious training. I guess you've picked up goodness knows what superstitious notions. But I'll see you get a proper education."
>
> "Thank you very much!" Tommy sat up hopefully. "I want to learn. Chandra Sha was teaching me Sanskrit and Arabic. I can speak Swahili and Urdu, and I'm studying the secret book of Rishabha—"
>
> "Heathen idolatry!" The blue eye and the brown widened in alarm. "Wicked nonsense you'll soon forget, here in Kansas. Simple reading and writing and arithmetic will do for the like of you, and a Christian Sunday school."
>
> "But Rishabha was the first Thirtankara," Tommy protested timidly. "The greatest of the saints. The first to find nirvana."
>
> "You little infidel!" Aunt Agatha's round pink face turned red. "But you won't find—whatever you call it. Not here in Kansas!  Now bring your things up to your room."

**One day she disappears and the boy notices an angry fly, with one brown eye and one green eye, stuck on the flypaper...**

> "Now don't you worry, little man," the sheriff boomed. "I'm come out to old Miz Grimm. Just tell me when you seen her last."
>
> "Here she is, right now," Tommy whispered faintly. "But if you haven't been instructed in the science of transmigration, I don't think you'll know her."
>
> He was leaning over one of the big yellow sheets of adhesive fly paper that Aunt Agatha liked to leave spread at night to catch flies while she slept. He was trying to help a large, blue fly that was hopelessly tangled and droning in its last feeble fury.
>
> "Pore little young-un!" The sheriff clucked sympathetically. "His aunt told me he was full of funny heathen notions!"
>
> He didn't even glance at the dying fly. But Tommy hadn't found it hard to recognize. Its right eye was a furious, greenish blue, the left was a tiny bead of wet brown glass.

**The story is from the 1960s, or thereabouts.**

First published in [*Fantastic*, March-April 1953](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?58323+c), available at the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/stream/Fantastic_v02n02_1953-03-04#page/n55/mode/2up). The quotations above are from the version in Jack Williamson's 1969 collection [*The Pandora Effect*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?45062), whose [cover](https://www.isfdb.org/wiki/images/6/6e/MLO242.jpg) was obviously inspired by this story. The 1953 magazine version differs in some details, e.g., the word "Negro" is omitted from the description of Aunt Agatha's accent, and the color of her right eye (and the fly's) is described as "bluish green" rather than "greenish blue".

Comment: That's it! Wonderful! Thanks!